# Pointer Error: Makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I'm brand new to C, and I'm trying to write a function that replaces a specific byte in an unsigned int. Pointers still have me a little fuzzy--would anyone care to explain to me exactly what my error is conceptually with these pointers in replace_byte()? Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;


void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int length) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

unsigned replace_byte(unsigned x, int i, unsigned char b) {
    int length = sizeof(unsigned);
    printf("X: ");
    show_bytes(x, length);
    printf("Replace byte position from left: %u\n", i);
    printf("Replace with: %u\n", b);
    printf("Combined: ");
    int locationFromRight = (length - i - 1);
    x[locationFromRight] =  b;
    show_bytes( (byte_pointer)&x, length);

}

int main(void) {

    unsigned a = 0x12345678;
    int loc = 2;
    unsigned char replaceWith = 0xAB;
    replace_byte(a, loc, replaceWith);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers rather than bitwise and?

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on bitewise operators, as well. Do you know of any resources that would describe what I'm attempting to do? I'm not sure what to google to get what I need :)

Comment: How about wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function definition

```
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int length)
```

takes a pointer as a first argument

```
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
```

however in the function `replace_byte()`

```
unsigned replace_byte(unsigned x, int i, unsigned char b)
```

you pass `x` which is declared as type `unsigned` to `show_bytes()`

```
show_bytes(x, length);
```

Comment: Read about big-endian versus little-endian.  If it doesn't make sense, reread it later.

Answer (score 0):

As I see `x` is not pointer in this call

```
show_bytes(x, length);
```

Which is against your function definition

```
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int length)  
                    ^
                    |
               Expects a pointer
```

In this statement

```
x[locationFromRight] =  b;
```

`x` is neithr pointer nor array.